# What is there in the data structure tree's value?

Tags: algorithm, find, union

I am studying algorithm union find.
But I don't mind with the value.

Example,
0 to 3 are connected on the one line.
So, we draw the line like this.
0 - 1 - 2 - 3

In this case, where I found the 3's parent? Where is the 3's parent the 2?

```cpp
int parent[1000001];

int Find(int x){

    if(x == parent[x]){
        return x;
    }
    else{
        int y = Find(parent[x]);
        parent[x] = y;
        return y;
    }

}

void Union(int x, int y){

    x = Find(x);
    y = Find(y);

    parent[y] = x;

}
```

Comment: _0 to 3 are connected on the one line_ If all 4 nodes in a single connectivity component, then all of `Find(0)`, `Find(1)`, `Find(2)` and `Find(3)` will produce the same number.

Comment: Trace it with pen and paper once.

Answer (score 0):

Which value actually becomes the parent of 3 depends on the order in which you unite pairs of values.

But first of all your code should initialise `parent` before connecting any points. When there are no connections yet, you must have for every `i`:

```
parent[i] = i
```

Then, if for instance your calls are like follows:

```
Union(0, 1)
Union(1, 2)
Union(2, 3)
```

...the parent relationship will evolve like this (pseudo code):

```
Union(0, 1)
   x := 0
   y := 1
   parent[1] := 0

Union(1, 2)
   x := 0  // because Find looks up the "root" of 1
   y := 2
   parent[2] := 0

Union(2, 3)
   x := 0  // because Find looks up the "root" of 2
   y := 3
   parent[3] := 0
```

#### Remark

Your implementation of Union Find has path compression, but does not improve tree-balancing with a size or rank attribute. The implementation becomes most efficient if it uses both strategies. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Time_complexity) on this topic.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back? Did this answer your question?